# How do I set up the data structure to make pie charts in GD::Graph?

Tags: perl, gd-graph

I am writting a Perl script to create pie graph using [GD::Graph::pie](http://search.cpan.org/dist/GD-Graph) with these arrays:

```
@Array1 = ("A", "B", "C", "D");
$array2 = [
      ['upto 100 values'],
      ['upto 100 values'],
      ['upto 100 values'],
      ['upto 100 values']
    ];
```

As per my understanding to get this done, I have to create an array with the references of above arrays, like:

```
 my @graph_data = (\@Array1, @$array2);
```

I have also tried to use `foreach` loop but not getting good results. I want to create pie graph with first value in `@Array1` against first value in `$array2` and second value in `@Array1` against second value in `$array2` and so on. Also I want put the same title for each graph as per values in `@Array1`.

```
eg.
my @graph_data1 = (\@Array1[0], @$array2[0]);
```

Can anyone please suggest me the better way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution of this problem using below code.

```
my @pairs = map{"$Array1[$_]@$array2[$_],"} 0..$#Array1;
```

After this the values from array @pairs can be used to create graphs.

Comment: I don't see how this solves your problem if you are trying to pass this to GD::Graph's plot() method.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure I understand what you are trying to do, but this example will produce 3 pie charts, all of them using the same set of categories. I would second Manni's advice: spend some time with [perlreftut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html) and [perldsc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html). Also, if you download the [GD::Graph](http://search.cpan.org/~bwarfield/GDGraph-1.44/Graph.pm) module, it provides many examples, including pie charts (see the `samples` subdirectory).

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use GD::Graph::pie;

my @categories = qw(foo bar fubb buzz);
my @data = ( 
    [   25,    32,    10,     44 ],  # Data values for chart #1
    [  123,   221,   110,    142 ],  # Data values for chart #2
    [  225,   252,   217,    264 ],  # etc.
);

for my $i (0 .. $#data){
    my $chart = GD::Graph::pie->new;
    my @pie_data = ( \@categories, $data[$i] );
    $chart->plot(\@pie_data);

    open(my $fh, '>', "pie_chart_$i.gif") or die $!;
    binmode $fh;
    print $fh $chart->gd->gif;
    close $fh;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Before getting into pie charts and stuff like that, I suggest you get yourself updated on basic Perl data structures and references. Please read [perlreftut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html), youl should be able to solve this problem yourself afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

To state in plainer English what the other answers say less directly:

```
my @graph_data = (\Array1, $@array2);
my @graph_data1 = (\Array1[0], $@array2[0]);
```

looks mad.  You almost certainly mean:

```
my @graph_data = (\@Array1, $array2);
# you want the first element of each list in the same datastructure?
my @graph_data1 = ([$Array1[0]], [$array2->[0]]); # (['A'], [[..numbers..]])
                                                  # Note *two* [ and ] in 2nd bit
# ... or you want a different datastructure?
my @graph_data1 = ($Array1[0], $array2->[0]); # ('A', [..numbers..])
```

@Array1 is an array, you want a reference to it, and that would be \@Array1.

$array2 is a reference to an array already. It contains references to arrays, and I assume you want a list containing the reference to the array at index 0.  Thus: $array2->[0] is the first indexed element via an array reference, and it's already an array reference.